# Does anyone have a suggestion for a good book on dikduk?

Tags: product-recommendation, hebrew, jewish-books, grammar-dikduk

I'm looking for a good book on dikduk for strictly **loshon hakodesh** (for studying tanach and talmud) . Any suggestions? in english preferably

Comment: Do you mean **leshon hakodesh**? What exactly does that mean to you? Please [edit] to use a more precise term. Wikipedia, for instance, lists a number of senses of the term http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leshon_Hakodesh If you want Tanakh related material only please specify if you want early or late Biblical Hebrew (eg http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23570/759)

Comment: possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30014/759

Comment: Not sure a Dikduk of Biblical Hebrew (if that's what you're looking for) will help much with Talmud study.

Comment: To clarify @SethJ, the Talmud is written in Aramaic; not Hebrew.

Answer (score 2):

My preferance is ספר **[דקדוקי שי](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%99.html?id=kNUXAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)** by  הר' שמואל מנדלבוים.

It's in Hebrew and introduces you step-by-step to Loshon Hakodesh's grammar.

Full disclosure: The author is my brother's brother-in-law.

Comment: Have you read it? It can't be very good if you still say "Loshon Hakodesh".

Comment: @DoubleAA - read it a long time ago, and grammar was never my strong point. BTW: It's cumbersome to transliterate the yekkishe Chowlem. :-)

Comment: Where is this book available for purchase?

Comment: @daniel - I asked my brother. His answer is: only from the author. The author can be reached at home in Jerusalem at (02)586-7913. FYI: R' Shmuli Mandelbaum speaks English.

Answer (score 1):

[A Practical Grammar for Classical Hebrew - Jaakov Wiengreen](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1682214.A_Practical_Grammar_for_Classical_Hebrew)

I find it useful, but it will mostly help you with Tanach, Talmud takes longer time since include aramaic and mishnaic hebrew as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image] Conact M. Guttman at Dikdukbooks@gmail.com for an extensive collection of Dikduk Books including Sefer Klalei Taamei Hamikra and others

Comment: Is it free or is this advertising?

Comment: @kouty Those two options aren't mutually exclusive | The OP didn't specify that books be free. || However, this doesn't specify any particular book as being recommended so it probably doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the Sefer [מפתח הדלת](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97-%D7%94%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%AA) to be extremely helpful, organized, and clear. It is in Hebrew.

For English, Rabbi Azriel Hauptman, a son-in-law of Rabbi Yosef Tendler ztz”l, used to teach a class on Dikduk at Ner Yisroel in Baltimore. He may be able to send you a PDF of the booklet he made for that.

For Aramaic grammar, “Grammar for Gemara and Targum Onkelos” by Yitzhak Frank is very helpful. However, I have found that a solid foundation in Hebrew grammar is necessary to fully appreciate the Aramaic.

Comment: There is also a recent book published call [Digdug: Dikduk with a Tickle](https://www.feldheim.com/digdug-dikduk-with-a-tickle-1)

Answer (score 0):

A good English introductory companion is

[Biblical Hebrew: An Introductory Grammar](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VxfnKGoo1dsC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Page H Kelley - It is very comprehensive and brings numerous examples in Tanach to demonstrate the various grammatical elements.

The Google Books review reads as follows:

> *Comprehensive in scope, this carefully crafted introductory grammar of Biblical Hebrew offers easy-to-understand explanations, numerous biblical illustrations, and a wide range of imaginative, biblically based exercises. According to Page Kelley, his book is "designed not so much for seasoned travelers as for those who are just starting out on a strange and wonderful journey."*
>
> *The book consists of thirty-one lessons arranged as follows: the nonverbal aspects of the language (lessons 1-10); the verb forms and their functions, with special attention to the strong verbs (lessons 11-20); the coordinate relationship of verbs, a topic alluded to but seldom developed in other grammars (lesson 21); and a comprehensive introduction to each of the ten classes of weak verbs (lessons 22-31). The grammar is accompanied by eleven complete verb charts, an extensive vocabulary list, a glossary of grammatical terms, and a subject index.*
>
> *Kelley employs a method that one reviewer has described as a cross between a straight presentation of grammatical principles and rules and a semi-inductive presentation of concepts through the exercises. Each lesson first presents new grammatical concepts, with biblical examples, and then provides reinforcing exercises that Kelley has judiciously selected from the biblical text (the exercises do not presuppose vocabulary and grammar not already covered).*
>
> *Deriving from the author's forty years of experience in teaching Biblical Hebrew to seminary students, and enthusiastically employed in its developing stages by instructors at a variety of colleges and seminaries, Kelley's Biblical Hebrew: An Introductory Grammar promises to be an excellent teaching tool with high potential as a textbook. Kelly has designed it for use in either a one-semester or a two-semester course.*