# What are the best books that teach Dikduk?

Tags: words, torah-study, jewish-books, grammar-dikduk

What are the best books to learn Dikduk? Both Lashon Hakodesh and Rabbinic/Mishnaic Hebrew.

Comment: I think this has been asked before? One sec...

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16526/which-books-help-one-acquire-a-systematic-understanding-of-biblical-hebrew-gramm

Comment: And this - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56741/does-anyone-have-a-suggestion-for-a-good-book-on-dikduk/118736#118736